# Add a char to a pipe Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

Hey guys right now I got a pipe which return letters as first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase of each word. it also removes all non-english characters from the value. I need to add the ':' char so it will allow it to show and not remove it, how can it be done?

Example now:

`@# test: me #@`

output:

`Test Me`

How It should be:

`Test: Me`

post my code below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'special'
    })
    export class SpecialPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: string): string {
        let newVal = value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.titleCase(newVal);
      }
      titleCase(str) {
       var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');

       for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {    
           splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
       }
       return splitStr.join(' '); 
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your regex to also exclude the : character from being removed:

```
value.replace(/[^\w\s:]/gi, '')
```

Comment: @hindi1991 you're welcome, and this is a good place to learn :)

Comment: To explain this: `[^...]` means that you exclude the characters in `...`.   `\w` means word-characters, which is letters, numbers and underscore. `\s` means whitespace character, such as a space, tab or new line. All you had to do was to add `:` inside the list of characters to exclude from the replacement function.